# Wpf кнопка в кнопке

Tags: c#, wpf

После нажатия кнопки "Начать" запускается программа. В конце мне нужно нажать на ещё одну кнопку "Решить". Как сделать кнопку в кнопке? Получаю сообщение об ошибке:

> Ошибка    CS0136  Локальная переменная или параметр с именем "sender" нельзя объявить в данной области, так как это имя используется во включающей локальной области для определения локальной переменной или параметра   pp4

Comment: я вам пытался помочь с двумя вопросами, но даже после этого не понимаю ваш третий вопрос. Попробуйте переформулировать его. Ну и, если вы получаете ошибку в коде, но показывайте и сам код, а не только ошибку.

Comment: Смотрите есть программа. В которой в текст бокс нужно ввести некоторое значение n. Есть кнопка "Начать", после нажатия этой кнопки появляется n - количество текстбоксов и n-1 количество комбобоксов между текстбоксами. 
Так  же у меня есть кнопка решить.
в текстбоксы записываются числа от -1231231231231 до +123123123123213 (Любые) В комбобокс можно выбрать(знак операции между числами) выглядит так при n = 2:
(Текст бокс куда вводим значение n)
(Кнопка начать) - при её нажатии появляется n -текстбоксов и n-1 комбобоксов выглядит это так
(Текстбокс)(Комбобокс)(Текстбокс)
(Кнопка решить)

Comment: Так вот. 
У меня вопрос.
Как мне сделать так , чтобы при нажатии на кнопку решить, после нажатия на кнопку начать, у меня вычислялся пример, который описан выше.

Comment: например, сделать 2 кнопки - одна Начать (скрывается после нажания, но делеает видимой вторую кнопку), вторая Решить (при нажатии решает что задал юзер).

Comment: у меня сделано уже две кнопки, вопрос в другом. Как мне брать значения из кнопки начать (Весь код у меня прописан там для создания текстбоксов и комбобоксов) Чтобы обратится к ним при нажатии на кнопку решить.

Comment: заведите поля в классе `private List<TextBox> _textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();` и добавляйте текстбоксы не только на форму, но и в эти поля. То же самое с комбобоксами. А в обработчике кнопки `Решить` смотрите в эти поля и считайте, что вам нужно.

Comment: создание контролов из кода, логика в обработчиках кнопки... вы из Делфи пришли?))